# Applying operations from the `calculator` package to conditional numerical values

Tags: latex, xelatex

I'm writing a LaTeX template that works similar to a spreadsheet: One defines a small number of variables and the whole document is adjusted accordingly.

I have three variables: `Level`, `ProficiencyBonus` and `AbilityScore`. Here is my MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calculator}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\Level{3}
\newcommand\ProficiencyBonus{%
\ifthenelse{\Level<5}{2}{3}%
}

\newcommand\AbilityScore{%
\ADD{\ProficiencyBonus}{10}{\TMP}%
\TMP%
}

Level: \Level \\
Proficiency Bonus: \ProficiencyBonus \\
Ability Score: \AbilityScore

\end{document}
```

This snippet produces and error during the addition:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

I suspect that `\ifthenelse` somehow doesn't return the "pure" number (are there "invisible" additional tokens?). However, I don't know how to debug this problem: I tried unsuccessfully to gain insight in the return value of `\ifthenelse` using `\show` and `\meaning`.

I'd appreciate any help that either solves this problem or shows me how to debug such a situation.

(I use XeLaTeX but this error appears also with normal LaTeX.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\ifnum` for your test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calculator}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\Level{3}
\newcommand\ProficiencyBonus{%
\ifnum\Level<5
  2
\else
  3
\fi
}

\newcommand\AbilityScore{%
\ADD{\ProficiencyBonus}{10}{\TMP}%
\TMP%
}

Level: \Level \\
Proficiency Bonus: \ProficiencyBonus \\
Ability Score: \AbilityScore

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem disappears when `\ifnum` is used. Do you have an idea why `\ifthenelse` is more problematic in this case?

Comment: @bloxx `\ifthenelse` is often problematic because of expansion issues.